# Integral of $(1-\ln x)\frac{dx}{x}$ , I get 2 different answers...?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is integral of $dx(1-\ln x)/x$.

I split the equation into $(1/x)dx-(lnx/x)dx$. Set $u=lnx$ for the right side of the equation, which evaluates into $\ln x-(1/2)((\ln x)^2) + C$

But the teacher set $u=1-\ln x$ , which evaluates $(-1/2)(1-\ln x)^2 + C$

which are different, in that if you plug in say 1 for $x$, my equation would evaluate to 0, while his would evaluate to -1/2. What am I missing? Thanks.

EDIT: Should mention this question asks for the definite integral from 1 to e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's wrong - the constant $C$ is arbritrary and note that $(1 -\ln x)^2 = 1 - 2\ln x + (\ln x)^2$, and we may absorb the $1$ into the constant $C$.

Comment: Thanks! Ok good I'm not going crazy. I guess I should have mentioned that this question was a definate integral between 1 and e so there's no C. Would ANY constant cancel out in the case of a definite integral?

Comment: @BobBobbert Yes. $$\int_a^b f(x) = \big[F(x) + c\big]_a^b = (F(b) + c) - (F(a) + c)=F(b) - F(a)$$ and no $c$'s.